# What would be the ideal solution to build AOSP project in the cloud for personal project

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I would like to setup a cloud Linux environment which will be used for building "AOSP" (Android Open Source Project) source code. I would like to set this environment in Google cloud (or) AWS. I am confused with what kind of storage solutions to go for, and what would be the ideal setup?

AOSP source code is approximately 200 GB in size.
After building, complete file size including the intermediate binaries is around 350 GB.

Basically i need minimum 400 GB of persistent disk space in cloud.

These are some of the options that i have been exploring.

**Options:**

1. 4 vCPU , 32 GB RAM with 600 GB SSD (Local storage) - Costly
2. 4 vCPU , 32 GB RAM , Preemptive instance , 600 GB (Local storage) - comparatively cheap, but no persistance of modified data.
3. 4vCPU, 32 GB , preemptive instance , 600 GB Persistent Storage - Cheap. I am not sure about the build performance as it has to retrieve the data from storage server for computation.

I could not find any relevant blogs that will answer the above question. if there are any ideal solutions please suggest.

Purpose : I am doing this for my personal project, so cannot afford Jenkins build system :)

Comment: How long is your budget? and what is the most important thing for you?(no downtime, more for less money, CPU performance, Disk IO)

Comment: Since its for personal project purpose  budget can be around 70 to 100 USD per month.  I am fine with downtime. But I want the build and data to be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

According with your budget I think that AWS and GCP are not so expensive, a machine like you describe are around 175 USD

I used the [GCP pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) and [AWS pricing Calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/addService) to get an approximation in the cost.

I found that AWS has discount if you reserve your VM for 1 year or 3 years.

Additionally, in [XDA forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=0644c3706472f87813ec292be7dc1535&t=1812253&page=20) you can check the time that takes compile  AOSP on some rigs.

I think that is better upgrade/buy a personal computer for this kind of tasks.